# window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission always returns "denied"

Tags: javascript, safari, apple-push-notifications

**EDIT**: I found the solution for implementing Safari Push Notifications and blogged about the process at: http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/how-to-implement-safari-push-notifications-on-your-website/

... When clicking "subscribe", it should enable push notifications for Safari 7.x on OSX 10.9.x.

Push notifications works on http://www.macrumors.com/ where they've implemented it. However, on my own test website, I always get "denied" as permission result without Safari even prompting it at all.

So: I don't get any prompt for allowing permission for push notifications, just a callback with `permissionData.denied`.

I found this question from SO with similar problem:
[Safari push notifications return denied without asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036446/safari-push-notifications-return-denied-without-asking)

But unfortunately it didn't offer me any advice.

Comment: I get a "Safari can't connect to the server" error when trying to access https://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/push

Comment: @Nick : that sounds "good" - since https: is not currently supported on the server. So you actually see the prompt and after allowing that you get the notification?

Comment: I think I solved this - the endpoint is not valid since it's not https and not serving correct content.

At first I was under assumption that .requestPermission() doesn't contact to server, but only browser API which prompts the user. But in fact it does.

Comment: @zvona - Best to post the solution as a separate "answer", rather than as part of the "question". So the answer is more obvious to others that run into the same problem down the road.

Answer (score 1):

When asking for permission, the browser contacts the endpoint that downloads the pushpackage of your site. The endpoint be restFUL and must run over "https". A self-signed SSL certificate does not work. Also, the push package must be valid for the user to be prompted. My advice is to get the logging endpoint working correctly so that you can at least know what is going on and where it's failing.